# What is wrong with my snake? Skin problem? Burn?

Tags: reptiles, snakes, temperature

Yesterday my snake was absolutely fine. This morning I went to pick her up for some handling and I noticed a weird mark on her skin, as I looked closer it appears there's a small amount of blood and the scales look a little weird. I think it's a burn, however, comparing it to images on Google it doesn't quite look the same.

Her heat lamp has a cage around it and the basking space stays at about 90 °F (32 °C) in the day time and at night I turn it down to 75 °F (24 °C). She never normally goes anywhere near (I mean as in climbing it or touching it, she still basks) the heat lamp and I haven't seen her around it the last couple of days. I touched after finding it and its not burning hot.

The only thing that is hotter than that is the UVB bulb. However, that is very high up and I can't see how her side would touch it. I know this is probably possible though, snakes slither everywhere! It's not burning hot like I can touch it but it is slightly hotter then 90 °F (32 °C) I think. Her heat lamps on a thermostat.

She is a 7-year-old corn snake, I got her 6 weeks ago. As Britain is now in effect in lockdown, I may not be able to take her to the vets and I don't want her to be in pain. It doesn't look too bad but I don't know what's behind the surface.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I will also attach a picture.

UPDATE: I e-mailed the vets and it is a superficial burn.

[image: re]

Comment: I hope one of our snake experts sees this post. I hope she is ok. The coronavirus is making it much harder in many ways.

Comment: Thank you,I emailed the vets and it is a superficial burn, so doesn't need any treatment and should heal on its own.Luckily she should be ok .Thank you.I know these times are making it much more difficult.

Comment: It's frightening times indeed. I'm glad she is ok. Perhaps consider posting an answer. Self answer questions are welcomed here.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out this is a superficial burn. Treatment is not needed so fingers crossed it will recover well.

Comment: Hi Isabelle, thank you for posting this answer to your question. You help future readers who have a similar problem. You can even accept your own answer, as described in the [tour]. That makes it visible to other people that they can find a well-founded answer in this post.